# How do I emulate logging in for controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

I have a SearchesController that requires a user to be logged in before it will do its thing.

I'd like to write an rspec helper function `login` to emulate logging in for controller tests.  (NB: I will handle integration / requests specs separately.)  My attempts so haven't worked: the `logged_in?` method in ApplicationController returns false.

The question: how do I write the 'login' helper?

Here's the RSpec controller test:

```
# file: spec/controllers/searches_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'controllers_helper'
describe SearchesController do
  include ControllersHelper

  describe "GET index" do

    it 'without login renders login page' do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(login_path)
    end

    it 'with login finds searches belonging to user' do
      me = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      my_searches = FactoryGirl.create_list(:search, 2, :user => me)
      not_me = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      not_my_searches = FactoryGirl.create_list(:search, 2, :user => not_me)

      login(me)  # want to define this in spec/controllers_helper.rb
      get :index
      assigns(:searches).should =~ my_searches
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the Controller:

```
# file: app/controllers/searches_controller.rb
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    unless logged_in?
      redirect_to login_path, :alert => "You must be logged in to access this page."
    else
      @searches = Search.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @searches }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And here's the ApplicationController code.  Note that `current_user = x` has the effect of logging x in, and it's rather simple: it sets @current_user and session[:user_id].

```
# file: app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  force_ssl

  protected

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
    session[:user_id] = user && user.id
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!@current_user
  end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      redirect_to login_path, :alert => "You must be logged in to access this page."
    end
  end

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?, :require_login
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I may have said this before, but if Stack Overflow gave badges answering one's own questions, I'd have a LOT of badges! :)*

Okay, to answer this question you need to look at the [documentation for ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html).  When you do so, you'll find that it sets up bindings for:

```
@controller
@request
@response
```

So for the specific controller given in the OP, writing the `login` method is trivial:

```
# file: spec/controllers_helper.rb
module ControllersHelper
  def login(user)
    @controller.send(:current_user=, user)
  end
end
```

(Did I hear someone say RTFM again?  I thought so...)